# How to ignore FluentValidation of specific property

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, fluentvalidation

Given the following two classes

```cs
public class AClass
{
    public string MyAString { get; set; }
}

public class BClass
{
    public AClass A { get; set; }
    public string MyBString { get; set; }
}
```

And also given the following two validators

```cs
public class AClassValidator : AbstractValidator<AClass>
{
    public AClassValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.MyAString).Length(10);
    }
}

public class BClassValidator : AbstractValidator<BClass>
{
    public BClassValidator()
    {
        // What to do here to ignore the validation on AClass.MyAString
    }
}
```

When I now have an action which receives `BClass` as a parameter. How can I write the BClass validator in a way that the existing validator on `AClass.MyAString` is not applied when checked in the context of `BClass`.

I tried `RuleFor(x => x.AClass.MyAString).Configure(x => x.ClearValidators());` but this didn't even work (and I didn't assume it to work, as the other validators might only be applied later on).

The "core" problem I'm facing is: We have a validator which checks for the existance of `AClass.MyAString` in the database, but for this specific `PUT` method I'd like to create the entry in the DB and therefor it will never exist when the actual request lands.

Comment: Have you got `ImplicitlyValidateChildProperties` set to true?

Comment: Wow thanks, this was / is actually the case. This happens implicitly in older Asp.Net integrations which are still using. We disabled it and changed all other "needed" child property validations to be explicit. Thanks!